# Jhipster xml generated for node_modules have error

Tags: node.js, jhipster

I am facing some issues setting it up intially.
When i import initial code generated by jhipster some xml generated under node_modules have error.
Since error is not in java src i can still use most of code but just wanted to know if it is normal?

Comment: Seems to be common in Eclipse/STS, this answer may help:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/29998037/3612124